# React Native PDF Signature

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-pdf

I’m trying to implement a pdf digital signature component for a react-native app.

I am using `react-native-pdf` for rendering the pdf on the screen and `react-native-draggable` for dragging the signature on top of the pdf view.

With `react-native-draggable` I can get the position of the signature on the screen but not related to the position on the pdf document.

Is there a way I can get/calculate the vertical position on the pdf?

I have to take into account different screen sizes, different pdf sizes, and different and variable margins. It looks more or less like this  [Refer to this image](http://share.getcloudapp.com/9ZuWeNEK)

Any formula/algorithm you can point as help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you achieve what you want on any screen? or share your code

Comment: @uokesita any progress so far?

Comment: @SobanArshad see my other comment

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make some progress, I think I can work from here
https://medium.com/bouncingshield/react-native-pdf-digital-signature-b63e12cdc714

Comment: Caution: This method has absolutely no legal value